# Delete single occurances in longitudinal data

Tags: r, count, dataframe, plyr

I am working with longitudinal data. I want to remove the observations of people that were only measured once (ids 5,7,9 below). How do I do this? Assume id is the unique identifier for people in the data set. Therefore, I would want to remove observations associated with ids 5,7, and 9. I've played with duplicated, unique, the table function, and the count function in plyr but haven't been successful. Example data below.

```
y<-sample(1:10, 20, replace=TRUE)
x<-sample(c(0,1),20, replace=TRUE)
id<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,7,8,8,8,9)
data<-data.frame(cbind(y,x,id))
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have received immediate assistance had you tagged the post as `R`,`data.frame`

Here, the `!` "not" function is used to remove `id` rows which match the values `c(5,7,9)`

```
> data[!data$id %in% c(5,7,9),]
   y x id
1  3 0  1
2  2 1  1
3  3 0  1
4  9 0  2
5  9 0  2
6  1 0  2
7  9 0  3
8  7 0  3
9  4 0  3
10 9 1  4
11 7 0  4
12 8 1  4
14 4 1  6
15 1 0  6
17 2 0  8
18 8 0  8
19 2 0  8
```

Comment: Obviously, this is just a sample data set. The above solution would be very tedious with 1000s of observations.